# GWT code isn't compiling

Tags: java, gwt

I am trying to  learn this new GWT part of java...

I made my first simple app

I named

- my module:- HelloWorld
- my entry point class :- hello
- and my html: index.html

I am getting this error:

> Apr 18, 2014 4:00:53 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences 
>   WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs
>   at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
>   Loading modules    com.test.GWTTestProject
>         Loading inherited module 'com.test.GWTTestProject'
>            [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/test/GWTTestProject.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a
>   classpath entry for source? [ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method

module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.6.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.6.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to="Hello">
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
    <source path="client" />
    <entry-point class="com.test.client.Home"></entry-point>
</module>
```

entry point class

```
package com.test.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

public class Home implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        RootPanel.get().add(new Label("Hello World"));
    }

}
```

index file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>index</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Hello/Hello.nocache.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is GWTTestProject.gwt.xml ? You need that file to compile. How did you created your project ?

Comment: I didnt created this file... I created the project using g sign that comes...

Comment: GTD Pulldown->new web application project

Comment: What IDE are you using ?

Comment: copy you module file to com/test/GWTTestProject.gwt.xml

Answer (score 0):

Error code 5 is "access denied".

Probably the key does not exist, and the user does not have the required permissions to create it.

Log on as administrator, start regedit, create a key named "Prefs" under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft (if it does not exist already) *and* assign full permissions to the key for the normal account you use.

Caveat emptor: messing up the registry will crash Windows, be careful.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, that's a WARNING.

Answer (score 0):

In the Eclipse's Project properties, in the GWT pane, remove the `GWTTestModule` that must have been added automatically at some point (if you renamed your module after creation, it might be that the Google Plugin for Eclipse forgot to take the rename into account everywhere)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you rename a GWT project there are possibilities that all of the things are not renamed and you will notice that some of things are stop working. In that case you have to rename it manually.

**I use a simple way to identify all the references of my last GWT project name by using Eclipse Search tool** as shown below snapshots.

I think you have renamed it to `HelloWorld` from `GWTTestProject`. Most probably you will find the matches in *.xml, .classpath, .project, *.html etc. Look at the matches and replace it manually as per your new project name.

**Remove all the previous stub and re-compile the project again.** I have highlighted all the stubs that needs to be deleted as shown in below snapshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I haven't rename the project

Comment: Have you tried to found out `GWTTestProject.gwt.xml` in your project using Eclipse Search tool?